# Strange Numbers shown in TexStudio Editor Menu

Tags: texstudio, menu

As seen in the attached figures, unusual characters are being displayed instead of the usual Arabic numerals. Despite attempting to `restore the default settings` or reinstall Texstudio, the issue persists.

- Texstudio version: 4.5.2
- TexLive version: TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023)
- OS: Windows 11

[image]

Comment: You do not clarify if you know that these symbols are  numbers in some Asian language or just nonsense symbols for you. My non-expert guess (spaniard using only Linux here) is that the issue is not related with texstudio but with the font/language settings of Windows.

Comment: @zi yuan Please go to settings->Time & Language -> Language & Region -> Administrative language settings. At the second option is your     `Language for non-Unicode programs`    other than English?

Comment: Characters may not be of Asian origin. A Google search ruled out Chinese, Japanese, and Korean. The font size in the image should be the number 9. Changing the Windows language from Chinese(my original windows language) to en-US resolved the issue, but it isn't perfect. I tried `Language for non-Unicode programs`, but it does not work. Hello @Fran and @miltos, it seems that your viewpoints are both right. It seems to relate to the Windows language setting. However, there is no clear solution to this issue.

Comment: Oh no! When I tried switching the language back to Chinese, the issue resolved itself. Perhaps the system rebooted? I'm not entirely sure, but it's certainly intriguing. Some unexplainable/random Windows bug?

Comment: Just guessing again, probably Windows use now the default font for Chinese, but the previous setting was changed/corrupted for some reason. System update? corrupted profile change?  viruses?  HD failure? sausage finger syndrome? global Warming?  魅鬼 ? ... who knows.  Traditional computers, without AI or quantum chips,  also make their own decisions sometimes.